# Meaning of "default on ... loans"

Tags: sentence-meaning

> Banks are not insured by government against default on the loans the banks make.

1. What is the meaning of "default on the loans" in this sentence?
2. When bank offers depositors lower interest, is it ok to say that bank is "paying" depositors lower interest? (In other words, is it ok to use the word "paying" rather than "offering" to have the same meaning?)

Comment: It might help you to think of it as *Banks are not insured by government against **the possibility that they might suffer** default on the loans they make*. Idiomatically you probably wouldn't want to repeat the word ***banks*** in such contexts. *Default* there means that the borrower fails to repay the loan, for whatever reason, so the banks lose their money.

Comment: so does "insured against default" mean insurance that insures you when people does not pay back their loan? It sounds confusing because of the word "against". If "insured for default" is used rather than "insured against default", it might sound more clear

Comment: I don't know where you get the idea that *it might sound more clear* if we used ***for*** rather than ***against*** in such contexts. Either would be perfectly comprehensible on purely pragmatic grounds with something like *buildings which were [insured against/for fire,*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=were+insured+against+fire%2Cwere+insured+for+fire&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwere%20insured%20against%20fire%3B%2Cc0), but consider *they were insured **for** an exorbitant sum*, where ***against*** is just nonsense.

Comment: ...the preposition ***against*** is natural here, since what it refers to *(loan defaults)* is something you'd like to be *protected **against***. We're usually ***for*** things we *want* to happen, and ***against*** things we don't like or want.

Answer (score 2):

When a person with a loan can no longer pay it back, they are said to

> default on their loan
>
> [If you don’t make your loan payments, you risk going into default.](https://studentaid.ed.gov/sa/repay-loans/default)

in these situations *whoever* made the loan may lose their money.

Banks in the US are insured by the federal government for their deposits, so customers do not lose all their money, however, the loans made by the banks are not insured.  So the situation is that the bank may go under (due to bad loans), but the depositors will be able to get their money back.

Using "pay" to describe what a bank pays on deposit is is perfectly fine

> [The money the bank pays you is called interest.](http://www.themint.org/teens/how-banks-work.html)